# Must all pages of a site have the same DOCTYPE?

Tags: html, dom

I made a website that has different pages, all of which have XHTML 1.0 Transitional DOCTYPE. Now i don't know much about doctypes but i'm learning as i go. My question may seem rather dumb but i searched almost everywhere and i was unable to find an answer to this simple question: Must all pages of a website have the same DOCTYPE?

I'm asking this because one of my pages has some input tags in which i used the attribute placeholder="name". The problem is that when i try to validate the code it says "**there is no attribute "placeholder"**" and as i understood the attribute "placeholder" is supported by HTML 5. I was wondering if i could use HTML 5 for this page in particular and leave the other pages as XHTML 1.0 Transitional.

Note: I cannot use javascript to get a similar behavior and also i don't really want to change all my pages to HTML 5 for various reasons.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DOCTYPE is declared per page, so there is no problem with different pages having different DOCTYPEs.

Comment: Just the answer i was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no *requirement* for them to be all the same doctype.

Comment: Of course, that doesn't mean I wouldn't recommend being consistent across a site.

Answer (score 0):

there is no problem with that

use the HTML5 DOCTYPE for all of your pages

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: I would, but i was instructed to use HTML5 and javascript only if necessary, other then that only use XHTML. I don't know much javascript so i don't want to go over my abilities, in case i get questioned so HTML5 for this page in particular seems like the only way to validate my code. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any harm in doing so, But I would recommend using the latest DOC-TYPE Available.

Please not if you are going to utilize the latest doc-type you may have to use an html5shiv for antiquated browsers.

Comment: Your recommendation was noted. Thank you very much.

Comment: using the html5 doctype doesn't change the requirement for htmlshiv in old IE. you still need it if you want to support ie8.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use the same DOCTYPE for all of your pages.

But I also recommend you to use the lastest available DOCTYPE. Some browsers will switch to the quirks mode if an antiqated (or no) DOCTYPE has been specified.

Answer (score 0):

They don't have to be the same doctype, but there's no real reason for them not to be.

Just make everything HTML5; your xhtml pages should still work just fine without ny other changes, but you'll be able to use all the new features.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't need to be but its recommended that you follow the same pattern across the board. Also use the html 5 doctype tag instead of 4 since everything is moving to HTML 5 now!